# Possible to use array values to create key-value type with corresponding string literals?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

```js
//###  Desired Implementation & Outcome:  ###//

function objectFromArray<T extends string[]>(...arr:T){
    return {/* do things */} as ObjectFromArray<T>
}

const foo = objectFromArray("a", "b", "c")

// foo === {a:"a", b:"b", c:"c"}

// typeof foo.a === "a"
// typeof foo.b === "b"
// typeof foo.c === "c"


//###  Attempt 1:  ###//
type ObjectFromArray<T extends any[]> = {[K in T[number]]: T[number]}
// no error, but results in unions instead of single values:
//   typeof foo.a === ("a" | "b" | "c")
//   typeof foo.b === ("a" | "b" | "c")
//   typeof foo.c === ("a" | "b" | "c")


//###  Attempt 2:  ###//
type ObjectFromArray<T extends string[]> = {[K in T[number]]: T[number][K]}
// Error: Type 'K' cannot be used to index type 'T[number]'.ts(2536)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this is what you mean:

```js
function objectFromArray<T extends string[]>(...arr:T){
    return {/* do things */} as ObjectFromArray<T>
}

type ObjectFromKeyList<KeyList extends string> = {[K in KeyList]: K}
type ArrayToKeyList<T extends any[]> = T extends (infer P)[] ? P : never
type ObjectFromArray<T extends any[]> = ObjectFromKeyList<ArrayToKeyList<T>>

const foo = objectFromArray("a", "b", "c")

foo.a // type is 'a'
```